CC/CV Battery charger with transistor
I'm designing a CC/CV charger with transistors and discrete components only.
My input will be 5 V, I'm designing this circuit without ICs to help me learn circuits without working with unknown internal circuit and as fun challenge, also this way the circuit is very cheap and with very few components, please don't answer by telling me to use an IC, the only IC I can work with is TL431 and only as a Zener with custom voltage, I know it can be used as a voltage regulator. (No op-amp either.)
In the circuit below is the constant current limiter. It is designed using a classic 2 NPN circuit, the battery is represented with a resistor (R2) 20 mOhm, I tried this part and it works fine.
My issue is the CV (constant voltage) part I tried too many ways to implement it but it doesn't work, first at high currents the Rsense (R1) will drop about 0.7 V at 1 A and the NPN will drop about 0.3 V (VCE) + the extra voltage needed to maintain the 1 A current, but the problem is when the battery gets in the CV part and draws less current the voltage drops change and the battery will get charged above 4.2 V.
I was thinking of using a normal silicone diode like the 1N4007 in series with the power supply to drop the voltage by 0.6-0.8 V, but still, at lower currents the voltage drop isn't reliable.
It will probably work, since the transistor also has a voltage drop between collector and emitter, but this solution isn't neat enough and very unreliable.
My second though was using a voltage divider on the battery to output 0.7 V or whatever the transistor needs on the base when the voltage reaches 4.2 V, but I got a little bit lost in simulators — when I read voltage across the resistor, it only gives me the voltage drop across the resistor, and when I change the resistor to high value i.e. simulating the end of the charge cycle, things started getting messy.
Also, since I'm only using transistors, I was connecting the emitter on the negative terminal of the battery which is the same as Q1 collector and the base of the transistor to 5 volts, however I tried connecting the collector to a lot of different nodes to turn off q1 but it didnt work, also instead of a voltage divider I used a zener of 3.5 V (TL431) connected to the base of the transistor that should work when it gets to 4.2 V, didnt work in simulation.
At this point I'm lost, I want to implement a neat way of regulating the voltage to 4.2 V with transistors, caps, diodes, etc.

Edit : I found a possible answer and I posted it, as far as I know this should work if it has any problems please tell me.

Another "I want to do "X", but without using the things people use to do "X" post.  Be careful. There are lots of safety issues with charging Li-Ion batteries, and you can easily get in trouble by starting a fire or getting injured.

In my opinion a few transistors and some discrete components could go very far, I'm doing this for learning, and copy pasting the example circuit from a datasheet isn't much learning, I have started with transistor oscillators, shmit trigger, emitter follower, current limiter and I have made amazing circuits and learned a ton , it is also very easy to upgrade the circuit when you know how each small part works, this is a part of much bigger circuit, an anlog battery capacity tester, I don't know yet how I will display capacity but it is a very fun task

Well, it's certainly possible, but I stand by my comment to be careful.  If not done correctly, component tolerances and temperature variation (for example) could easily cause overcharging or other issues, which can lead to fire or injury.

I tried this circuit but only the simplest version, but I can check the more reliable options that I wasn't aware about mentioned in the same site, my problem though is that I have a very small voltage difference between output and input, therefore the vbe which fluctuates with current is problematic, in my design since my input is 5v and output is 4.2v it doesnt really need a zener at 4.9v , I could tie the base directly to the collector which makes it a diode, however using the other ways of improving the circuit might actually be a good idea even if the transistor is acting as a diode

sure John D, I know how dangerous lithium batteries can get this why I don't want to experiment without an expert opinion this is why I asked here

But you have an XY problem. You want to charge batteries with a 5V supply which is an arbitrary selection. Either change to higher voltage supply, or if you can't do that, then use an IC to boost up the voltage first. Or do it with discrete components. Don't get stuck on things that are not issues. Also the diodes are likely silicon diodes. Silicone is typically used elsewhere.

Bumbing up the voltage would certainly make things easier, however it is really a bad design if I can't work with what I have, efficiency will drop, I will need a good inductor, an oscillator with feedback, it seems an overkill also boosting at a current of 1A has a much higher switching currents, that is a big wasteful design and for what my output is within 0.8v from input, I definitely think it is a way arround but a very bad way

Ok so I tried a couple of different Ideas and I found a possible solution to my question.
I added a voltage divider RD1/RD2 across the battery, I fed it to a PNP transitor Q3 if the voltage across the battery is higher than 4.2V it turns off, if it turns off it stops Q2 and Q1, by defualt if the battery is lower than 4.2v, Q3 turns on and Q2 and Q1, the other part of the circuit stays the same for the current limiting.
Although I used 3 extra transistors I think it very relaible and most transistors will be small current transitors.
Q1 could be replaced with a MOSFET to reduce vbe, this circuit could achieve a very low dropout of 0.4v, 0.3 vbe of Q4, and the shunt could drop to 0.1 ohm and an amplifier before the base of Q5.


The first thing I did was to do a web search for "CCCV power supply circuit only transistors".
Here is one result: http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Power_Supply_Circuit/CCCV_Lithium_Battery_Charge_Control_Schematic_Circuit.html

{Source: seekic.com}
There are more results, including this one: https://www.homemade-circuits.com/how-to-make-versatile-variable-voltage/

These solutions don't appear to have a charge termination method.  At best, "float" charging Li-Ion batteries can reduce the life of the battery, at worst it can cause ignition and reduce the life of the user.  Also, these simplistic solutions don't have a mechanism for recovery charging of an over-discharged cell, which can also be dangerous. Though the OP doesn't want to hear it, for others reading the question it's best to use an IC charger with safety protections (recovery charging, charge termination, watchdog timer, temperature monitoring) to safely charge lithium batteries.

This solution is indeed promising but it has 2 main issues first res is 4.7 ohms at 1A it will drop 4.7v so I'm left with 0.3v not enough to turn on Q1, I can change the value, but also the design relies on the hfe of q2 to limit current and a bit on the voltage droped by the 3W res, using hfe for current limiting is very unrelaible, the tl431 is useless in this situation since at an input of 5v I will need to set it up to 4.2 +VBE Q1 + VBE Q2 + voltage drop across the input resistor, so it will not work in this case as it will need higher voltage than  input, might work at higher voltage only
